# Plot clustered heatmaps with huge file in python?

Tags: python, heatmap

I have three files, each around 3Gb in size, containing genome mapping info like this:

```
#RefName    Pos Coverage
BGC0000001_59320bp  0   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  1   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  2   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  3   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  4   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  5   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  6   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  7   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  8   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  9   0
BGC0000001_59320bp  10  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  11  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  12  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  13  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  14  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  15  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  16  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  17  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  18  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  19  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  20  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  21  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  22  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  23  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  24  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  25  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  26  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  27  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  28  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  29  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  30  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  31  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  32  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  33  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  34  0
BGC0000001_59320bp  35  0

.
.
.
.
```

First column = gene name; 2nd column = position or loci of every base of the gene; 3rd column =  coverage of every base or position.

For example:
the first gene 'BGC0000001_59320bp' is 59320bp long, so there will be 59320 rows for this gene, and then next gene shows up.

I'd like to make a clustered heatmap like this:
[image]

The y axis is every gene, such as BGC0000001,BGC0000002,....
The x axis is binned gene position. Because every gene has different length, I will bin them into the same number of bins, say 100 bins. This makes the x axis become bin1, bin2, bin3, ..., bin100. For example, BGC0000001 = 59320 bp, BGC0000002= 10000bp, I'll group every gene into 100 bins, so for BGC0000001, bin1 = 593bp, bin2 = 593bp, ...bin100= 595bp; for BGC0000002, bin1 = 100bp, bin2 = 100bp ...bin100 = 100bp. I'll put the sum of the coverage into every bin as values for plotting. For example: for BGC0000001, bin1 = sum(coverage of the first 593bp), bin2 = sum(coverage of the 2nd 593bp) ...

Finally, I'll use the binned data for clustered heatmap plotting. I have three sample files to make three plots. Because the data is huge, I'm trying the code below, which is really not clean, and it takes forever:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

import seaborn as sns



def getFiles(filePath):
    coverageFile = []    

    for file in os.listdir(filePath):
        if file.endswith(".coverage"):
            coverageFile.append(file)
        else:
            pass          

    print(coverageFile)

    return coverageFile



def binCov(df,name,nBins):
    genomeMap = df[df.node == name].coverage
    bin_sums, bin_edges, binnumber = binned_statistic (range(len(genomeMap)), genomeMap, 
                                                        statistic = 'sum', bins = nBins)
    bin_width = (bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0])
    bin_centers = bin_edges[1:] - bin_width*0.5

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'covSum':bin_sums})

    df1.insert(1,'gene',name)
    df1.insert(2,'loci',range(1, len(df1)+1))
    df1.insert(2,'covNorm',df1.covSum)
    df1.loc[df1.covSum >5000, 'covNorm'] = 5000
    df1.drop('covSum', axis =1, inplace = True)

    return df1


files = getFiles(os.getcwd())

df_nac = pd.read_csv(files[0], sep = '\t')
df_nac.columns = ['node', 'loci', 'coverage']


df_ks = pd.read_csv(files[1], sep = '\t')
df_ks.columns = ['node', 'loci', 'coverage']

df_meta = pd.read_csv(files[2], sep = '\t')
df_meta.columns = ['node', 'loci', 'coverage']

cluster_names = df_nac.node.tolist()

cluster_nac = {}
cluster_ks = {}
cluster_meta = {}


for name in cluster_names:
    cluster_nac[name] = binCov(df_nac, name, 100)
    cluster_ks[name] = binCov(df_ks, name, 100)
    cluster_meta[name] = binCov(df_meta, name, 100)

cluster_nac_all = pd.concat(cluster_nac.values(), ignore_index=True)
cluster_ks_all = pd.concat(cluster_ks.values(), ignore_index=True)
cluster_meta_all = pd.concat(cluster_meta.values(), ignore_index=True)


nac_p = cluster_nac_all.pivot("gene", "loci", "covNorm")
ks_p = cluster_ks_all.pivot("gene", "loci", "covNorm")
meta_p = cluster_meta_all.pivot("gene", "loci", "covNorm")



sns.set_style("darkgrid")

plt.figure(figsize = (5,10))
# cmap="Greens", , linecolor='yellow', alpha = 0.9,cmap="YlGnBu"
g1 = sns.heatmap(meta_p, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, cmap="BuPu", cbar = False)

g1.set_xlabel('Bases (binned)')
g1.set_ylabel('')

g1.set_xticks([])
g1.set_yticks([])

plt.savefig('meta_sumCov.png',dpi = 300, bbox_inches = 'tight')

plt.figure(figsize = (5,10))
# cmap="Greens", , linecolor='yellow', alpha = 0.9,cmap="YlGnBu"
g2 = sns.heatmap(nac_p, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, cmap="BuPu", cbar = False)

g2.set_xlabel('Bases (binned)')
g2.set_ylabel('')

g2.set_xticks([])
g2.set_yticks([])

plt.savefig('nac_sumCov.png',dpi = 300, bbox_inches = 'tight')

plt.figure(figsize = (5,10))
# cmap="Greens", , linecolor='yellow', alpha = 0.9,cmap="YlGnBu"
g3 = sns.heatmap(ks_p, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, cmap="BuPu", 
    cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec=False,location="right"))

g3.set_xlabel('Bases (binned)')
g3.set_ylabel('')

g3.set_xticks([])
g3.set_yticks([])

plt.savefig('ks_sumCov.png',dpi = 300, bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

I let it run for 10hours now and still going, although it did not show any error.
I don't think Pandas is good for large files, but I'm not familiar with other faster tools. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: So the `for name in cluster_names:` loop will loop several billion times?

Comment: And do I understand correctly: There are different genes named `BGCxxxxxxx`. Each of them can have a different `pos`. You want a heatmap of how many genes of type `BGCxxxxxxx` are in a certain `pos` range.

Comment: The first column is gene name, such as BGC0000001, BGC0000002..... BGC0014560. Each gene has a different length of pos. For example, BGC0000001 has pos: 1, 2, 3, 4...53920. BGC0000002 has pos: 1, 2, 3, 4...100000. BGC0000003 has pos: 1, 2, 3, 4...120000. I want to bin the data first like this: first column, still BGC0000001, BGC0000002..... BGC0014560. 2nd column becomes bin1, bin2, bin3, .... bin100. 3rd column becomes: sum(coverage in bin1),sum(coverage in bin2),sum(coverage in bin3)... And then use the binned data to create a heatmap. Thank you.